# Why is ICMP (ping) request blocked, when sending to HTTPS server when port 443 is blocked by iptables filter?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, icmp

**ICMP Protocol is not using either TCP or UDP**
as far as I understand doesn't use the concept of ports.

So I blocked outgoing packets on port 433 i.e going to an *HTTPS* server:

```
(sudo) iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
```

now, if I ping any HTTPS server I hoped traffic would pass through
but it didn't.

why is this so?

Does the ping request somehow adopt the port open (443) of the HTTPS server?

Comment: What's the output of `iptables -L`?

Answer (score 2):

No, ICMP is a network layer protocol and has no concept of ports.

Assuming that you can make requests to the web server and receive responses, and without knowing the network topology / network configurations, the most probable cause is that some other network device along the path is filtering ICMP packets.